# How to trigger NFC by program or Adb shell?

Tags: java, android, adb, nfc, android-sdk-tools

I am using a remote machine to develop a NFC app, so I cannot put the NFC tag on device for each testing

If I can trigger NFC by program or adb, I can test the app easily. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't know if there are any programs to simulate the NFC tag, but I'm certain there is no NFC emulation from ADB.

Comment: I have a real NFC tag, I just cannot every time put the tag on device by human hand, I need place the tag on device, and trigger device to read the tag